# How prove $\frac{x^{3}+y}{y^{3}+x}-1\geq \ln \frac{(x^{2}+1)^{2}}{x}-\ln \frac{(y^{2}+1)^{2}}{y}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How prove $\frac{x^{3}+y}{y^{3}+x}-1\geq \ln \frac{(x^{2}+1)^{2}}{x}-\ln \frac{(y^{2}+1)^{2}}{y}$ where $x, y\geq 1$?

Comment: I think the condition is wrong, it should be $x\ge y$. hint:$x-1 \ge \ln{x}$

Comment: If    $x \ge y \ge 1$ then $\frac{(x^2+1)^2}{x}  \cdot  \frac{y}{(y^2+1)^2}  \ge 1$ and what next?

Comment: $\frac{x^3+y}{y^3+x}\ge \frac{(x^2+1)^2}{x}  \cdot  \frac{y}{(y^2+1)^2}  $

Comment: Probably not, because for  $x \ge y \ge 1$ is right ineq $\frac{(x^2+1)^2}{x}  \cdot  \frac{y}{(y^2+1)^2}  \ge \frac{x^3+y}{y^3+x}$  $\iff$ $\frac{(xy-1)(x^2-y^2)(x-y)^2}{(y^3+x)(y^2+1)^2x} \ge 0$

Comment: ya ,I make a mistake. I have a solution to post soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $x=ay \ge 1$

it is trivial when $a=1$, LHS=RHS

so we only discuss $a>1 $ or $ a<1 $

$f(y)=\dfrac{a^3y^2+1}{y^2+a}-1-2\ln{((ay)^2+1)}+2\ln{(y^2+1)}+\ln{a}$

$f'(y)=\dfrac{2(a-1)^2(a+1)y(a^3y^4+a^2y^4+2ay^4+2y^4+a^3y^2+a^2y^2+3ay^2-y^2-a-1)}{(y^2+1)(y^2+a)^2(a^2y^2+1)}>0 $

because $a^2y^4 \ge y^2,ay^4 \ge a,a^2y^2>1$

so we check $y_{min}$ for $f_{min}$

when $a>1, y_{min}=1 ,f(1)=a^2+a-\ln{\dfrac{(a^2+1)^2}{4a}}\ge a^2+a-\left(\dfrac{(a^2+1)^2}{4a}-1\right)=\dfrac{(a+1)(3a^3+a^2+a-1)}{4a}>0$

when $a<1,y_{min}=\dfrac{1}{a}, f(\dfrac{1}{a})=\dfrac{a-1}{a^2-a+1}-\ln{\dfrac{4a^3}{(a^2+1)^2}} \ge \dfrac{a-1}{a^2-a+1} - \dfrac{4a^3}{(a^2+1)^2}+1=\dfrac{a^2}{a^2-a+1}-\dfrac{4a^3}{(a^2+1)^2}=\dfrac{a^2(a-1)^4}{(a^2+1)^2(a^2-a+1)}>0$